# What is causing my consumer to be sent 2 arguments--one, in addition to the "message"?

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm implementing the [multichat](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/multichat) example and unable to figure out what's causing this error. Here's the full traceback:

```
2018-01-05 07:35:48,017 - ERROR - worker - Error processing message with consumer chat.consumers.chat_join:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sng/.virtualenvs/blog-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 119, in run
    consumer(message, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sng/.virtualenvs/blog-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 78, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sng/.virtualenvs/blog-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 42, in inner
    return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sng/Dev/django/blog-api/src/chat/utils.py", line 14, in inner
    return func(message, args, **kwargs)
TypeError: chat_join() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I believe I've copied the code nearly as is, so I don't know how it went wrong.

Here's the consumer:

```
@channel_session_user
@catch_client_error
def chat_join(message):
    room = get_room_or_error(message["room"], message.user)    
    if NOTIFY_USERS_ON_ENTER_OR_LEAVE_ROOMS:
        room.send_message(None, message.user, MSG_TYPE_ENTER)

    room.websocket_group.add(message.reply_channel)
    message.channel_session['rooms'] = list(set(message.channel_session['rooms']).union([room.id]))

    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": json.dumps({
            "join": str(room.id),
            "title": room.title,
        }),
    })
```

Routing:

```
custom_routing = [
    route("chat.receive", chat_join, command="^join$"),
    route("chat.receive", chat_leave, command="^leave$"),
    route("chat.receive", chat_send, command="^send$"),
]
```

In regular Django, I think the parallel would be the URLconf sending one too many args to the view. I'm not sure where `message` is being sent from, and so unsure if anything else is being sent alongside it. The traceback hints at it being caused in relation to sessions. Not quite sure where, or how to debug in that domain.

EDIT: I forgot to note: this doesn't happen on `runserver`, it happens when I try and enter a chat room. Here is related code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block head_title %}MultiChat Example{% endblock %}
{% block header_text %}MultiChat Example{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<ul class="rooms">
    {% for room in rooms %}
        <li class="room-link" data-room-id="{{ room.id }}">{{ room.id }}</li>
    {% empty %}
        <p class="empty">No chat rooms defined. Maybe make some in the <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">admin</a>?</p>
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>

<div id="chats">
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

So when I click on one of the rooms, the error will pop up and refuse to open.

The JS file:

```
$(function () {
    // Correctly decide between ws:// and wss://
    var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
    var ws_path = ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + "/chat/stream/";
    console.log("Connecting to " + ws_path);
    var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(ws_path);

    // Helpful debugging
    socket.onopen = function () {
        console.log("Connected to chat socket");
    };
    socket.onclose = function () {
        console.log("Disconnected from chat socket");
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (message) {
        // Decode the JSON
        console.log("Got websocket message " + message.data);
        var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
        // Handle errors
        if (data.error) {
            alert(data.error);
            return;
        }
        // Handle joining
        if (data.join) {
            console.log("Joining room " + data.join);
            var roomdiv = $(
                "<div class='room' id='room-" + data.join + "'>" +
                "<h2>" + data.title + "</h2>" +
                "<div class='messages'></div>" +
                "<input><button>Send</button>" +
                "</div>"
            );
            $("#chats").append(roomdiv);
            roomdiv.find("button").on("click", function () {
                socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                    "command": "send",
                    "room": data.join,
                    "message": roomdiv.find("input").val()
                }));
                roomdiv.find("input").val("");
            });
            // Handle leaving
        } else if (data.leave) {
            console.log("Leaving room " + data.leave);
            $("#room-" + data.leave).remove();
        } else if (data.message || data.msg_type != 0) {
            var msgdiv = $("#room-" + data.room + " .messages");
            var ok_msg = "";
            // msg types are defined in chat/settings.py
            // Only for demo purposes is hardcoded, in production scenarios, consider call a service.
            switch (data.msg_type) {
                case 0:
                    // Message
                    ok_msg = "<div class='message'>" +
                        "<span class='username'>" + data.username + "</span>" +
                        "<span class='body'>" + data.message + "</span>" +
                        "</div>";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Warning/Advice messages
                    ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-warning'>" + data.message + "</div>";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Alert/Danger messages
                    ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-danger'>" + data.message + "</div>";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // "Muted" messages
                    ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-muted'>" + data.message + "</div>";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // User joined room
                    ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-muted'>" + data.username + " joined the room!" + "</div>";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    // User left room
                    ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-muted'>" + data.username + " left the room!" + "</div>";
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Unsupported message type!");
                    return;
            }
            msgdiv.append(ok_msg);
            msgdiv.scrollTop(msgdiv.prop("scrollHeight"));
        } else {
            console.log("Cannot handle message!");
        }
    };

    // Says if we joined a room or not by if there's a div for it
    function inRoom(roomId) {
        return $("#room-" + roomId).length > 0;
    };

    // Room join/leave
    $("li.room-link").click(function () {
        roomId = $(this).attr("data-room-id");
        if (inRoom(roomId)) {
            // Leave room
            $(this).removeClass("joined");
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                "command": "leave",  // determines which handler will be used (see chat/routing.py)
                "room": roomId
            }));
        } else {
            // Join room
            $(this).addClass("joined");
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                "command": "join",
                "room": roomId
            }));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in the code of your decorator, which you're not showing - the traceback says that chat/utils.py line 14 has

```
return func(message, args, **kwargs)
```

when it should be

```
return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
```

Presumably the second argument is an empty tuple.